# Why does Gazebo executes two times?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

When I open Gazebo:

```
gazebo --verbose
```

Gazebo is called two times:

```
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 8.1.1
Copyright (C) 2012 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

[Msg] Waiting for master.
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 8.1.1
Copyright (C) 2012 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org
```

Why it is executed two times?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/16463/why-does-gazebo-executes-two-times?/) by [michael1234](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3329/michael1234/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 5 on 2017-06-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

When you open Gazebo, you spin up two processes:

- a server `gzserver` for simulating the physics, rendering, and sensors
- a client `gzclient` that provides a graphical interface to visualize and interact with the simulation

It's also possible to run these processes separately.

You can read more on Gazebo's architecture on [this](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=architecture&cat=get_started) tutorial.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2017-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [michael1234](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3329/michael1234/) on 2017-06-17**:
A detailed answer, thanks!